# How to check if an element is available in a database?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I've started a C# console(.net framework) and I want to insert into the database a new *reservation*, but first of all I have to check if the car that I want to rent exists and is available (it is not in rent).
By available I mean that the time interval in which I want to rent the car should be free. And this is my problem. How can I check it by having the start time and end time? Is there a special query for this?

For example, if I want to rent a car between 12 and 13.05.2020 the query will be something like ?

```
Select StartDate, EndDate
from Reservations 
where (StartDate < 'startDate = 12/05/2020' and EndDate > 'startDate = 12/05/2020') or (StartDate < 'endDate = 13/05/2020' and EndDate > 'endDate = 13/05/2020')
```

Here is what I tried with car existcence:

```
public bool validateCartRentData(CartRent rent)
        {
            bool validation = true;

            using (databaseConnection = new SqlConnection())
            {
                try
                {
                    setDatabaseConection();
                    databaseConnection.Open();

                    string query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Cars] WHERE ([Plate] = @Plate)";
                    SqlCommand checkCarModel = new SqlCommand(query, databaseConnection);

                    checkCarModel.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Plate", rent.car.plate);
                    int carExists = (int)checkCarModel.ExecuteScalar();

                    Console.WriteLine(carExists);

                    if (carExists < 0)
                    {
                        return validation;
                    }

                }
                catch (SqlException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                }

                return false;
            }
        }
```

Here is my Database model:

[Database model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbHNB.png)

I'm using a database for the first time, so don't be too harsh with me, please! Thank you!

Comment: You want a car from 2pm to 4pm. So if someone had a rental that ended between 2pm and 4pm, _or_ started between 2pm and 4pm, _or_ started before 2pm and ended after 4pm - that would be a problem. That may get you started.

Comment: I was thinking about that but I don't really know how to formulate the query.

Comment: There are three rules in my comment. Try implementing **one** of them to start with. Show us that attempt.

Comment: Do it in SQL Server Management Studio first, before trying to do it in C#.

Comment: Ok, I will try it now. Thank you!

Comment: is the query correct?

Comment: I suggest you start over as already suggested. Forget about your application code. Post DDL for your tables and include some sample data. Then post a couple of queries that test for the situations that have already been mentioned. Get those working and you can then implement that checking in your application code.

Comment: And don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: thank you guys for the ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```sql
> Select StartDate, EndDate
> from Reservations 
> where (StartDate < 'startDate = 12/05/2020' and EndDate > 'startDate = 12/05/2020') or (StartDate < 'endDate = 13/05/2020' and EndDate > 'endDate = 13/05/2020')
> ```

First off, if the start and end dates are our inputs, we would want to output something else, probably something like `carID`

When looking at the dates, we need the reservation to end before the new one begins, or for the new one to start after the old reservation ends.  There is an assumption here that a reservation will never end before it starts, which I hope is safe.  ;)

`NewStart` and `NewEnd` are the new reservation dates we want to check against.

```sql
SELECT carID
FROM Reservations
WHERE (StartDate > NewEnd) OR (EndDate < NewStart)
```

This would give us a list of all the cars that have a rental that does not overlap with our new rental.  This may, however include a car that has another rental that does.  If we negate the `WHERE` statement, we can get a list of `carID`'s that have a reservation that invalidates.  Then we just need a list of `carID`'s that are not in **that** list:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT carID /*Available Cars*/
FROM Reservations /*Could also take this from a cars table*/
WHERE carID NOT IN 
(SELECT carID /*Unavailable Cars*/
FROM Reservations
WHERE NOT((StartDate > '2020-05-16') OR (EndDate < '2020-05-14')))
```

### Summary:

A valid reservation starts after, or ends before our new reservation.  Get a list of all the cars with INVALID reservations.  Get a list of all cars not on the previous list.